How to include Collision monitor node in nav2 navigatoin launch?
Im using ROS2 humble on Ubuntu 22.04 and nav2. I have the navigation parameter file yaml file configure like this with the Collision monitor
collision_monitor:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    base_frame_id: "base_link"
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    cmd_vel_in_topic: "cmd_vel_smoothed"
    cmd_vel_out_topic: "cmd_vel_nav"
    transform_tolerance: 0.2
    source_timeout: 5.0
    base_shift_correction: True
    stop_pub_timeout: 2.0
    # Polygons represent zone around the robot for "stop" and "slowdown" action types,
    # and robot footprint for "approach" action type.
    # Footprint could be "polygon" type with dynamically set footprint from footprint_topic
    # or "circle" type with static footprint set by radius. "footprint_topic" parameter
    # to be ignored in circular case.
    polygons: [ "PolygonSlow", "FootprintApproach"]
    PolygonSlow:
      type: "polygon"
      points: [0.6, 0.6, 0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, -0.6, 0.6]
      action_type: "slowdown"
      max_points: 3
      slowdown_ratio: 0.9
      visualize: True
      polygon_pub_topic: "polygon_slowdown"
    FootprintApproach:
      type: "polygon"
      action_type: "approach"
      footprint_topic: "/local_costmap/footprint"
      time_before_collision: 1.0
      simulation_time_step: 0.1
      max_points: 5
      visualize: True
    observation_sources: ["scan", "pointcloud"]
    scan:
      type: "scan"
      topic: "/velodyne_points"
    pointcloud:
      type: "pointcloud"
      topic: "/dept/color/points"
      min_height: 0.1
      max_height: 0.5

Then would like to include  Collision monitor node into my nav2_navigation.launch.py file. My understanding is that has to be in the nav2_navigation.launch file and not into nav2_bringup.launch.py file.
So here is the nav2_navigation.launch.py file where collision monitor parts are included
lifecycle_nodes = ['controller_server',
                       'smoother_server',
                       'planner_server',
                       'behavior_server',
                       'bt_navigator',
                       'waypoint_follower',
                       'collision_monitor']
...
load_nodes = GroupAction(
        condition=IfCondition(PythonExpression(['not ', use_composition])),
        actions=[
            Node(
                package='nav2_controller',
                executable='controller_server',
                output='screen',
                respawn=use_respawn,
                respawn_delay=2.0,
                parameters=[configured_params],
                remappings=remappings),
            Node(
                package='nav2_collision_monitor',
                executable='collision_monitor',
                output='screen',
                emulate_tty=True,  
                parameters=[configured_params])
...

load_composable_nodes = LoadComposableNodes(
        condition=IfCondition(use_composition),
        target_container=container_name,
        composable_node_descriptions=[
            ComposableNode(
                package='nav2_controller',
                plugin='nav2_controller::ControllerServer',
                name='controller_server',
                parameters=[configured_params],
                remappings=remappings),
            ComposableNode(
                package='nav2_collision_monitor',
                plugin='nav2_collision_monitor::CollisionMonitorNode',
                name='collision_monitor',
                parameters=[configured_params]),
                remappings=remappings),

But still in the simulation Im not able to visualize the polygons of the collision Monitor.
Any help how to correctly implement collision Monitor node in ROS2 humble Nav2?
